# Kotlin - Center message in AlertDialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, centering

I'm trying to center the message of AlertDialog without adding custom view like I did for title. I have tried some of the older answers on SO, but I get `null` into `mw`.

Is this approach simply not possible and custom TextView as message is the only way?

```
val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this).create()
alertDialog.setMessage("boop")
val title = TextView(this)
title.setText(R.string.myresource)
title.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10)
title.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
title.textSize = 20F
alertDialog.setCustomTitle(title)

alertDialog.show()

val mw = alertDialog.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.message)
mw.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `R.id.message` to `android.R.id.message` since you want a view that was declared in the android package.

```
val mw = alertDialog.findViewById<TextView>(android.R.id.message)
mw.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Comment: Are there any other known ids for further custimization of the alert dialog, like the buttons or the layout itself?

Comment: @mTak You can get the icon with `android.R.id.icon`, but if you want buttons, there is a method in AlertDialog for it called [getButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog#getButton(int)) `dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)`.

Comment: That will do. Thanks